# Display data for two tables to layout page MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two models and I need to display data in my layout page and in every page that the user visit. Those two models have not any relationship between them so I don't need any join.

this is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var notification = (from n in db.Notification
                            where n.NotificationIsSeen == true
                            select n);



        var task = (from t in db.Task
                          where t.TaskIsSeen == true
                            select t);

        return View();// I not sure how to return both of queries
    }
```

I also create a model that contains both of them but I 'not sure if this is the right way

```
public class Layout
{


    public Notification Notification { get; set; }
    public Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

and in my layout page

```
@model IEnumerable<MyprojectName.Models.Layout>

//other code 
@foreach (var item in Model) 
 {
  <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notification.NotificationSubject ) </li>}

//other code
@foreach (var item in Model) 
 {
  <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Task.TaskSubject ) 
  </li>
  }
```

I have seen other similar question but they work with join tables.
 I need some help on returning data of both tables. thank you in advance

Comment: You queries return collections, so your view model needs to be `public class Layout { public IEnumerable<Notification> Notifications { get; set; } publicIEnumerable<Task> Tasks { get; set; } }` and return a single instance of `Layout` to the view.

Comment: There is some confusion about what you need. Your model has a single `Notification` and `Task`, but in your action method you are getting a collection of both. You view shows that it needs a collection of your viewmodel. Can you clarify what is the intended behavior

Comment: Stephen Muecke.  What do you mean of returning a single instance of Layout? thank you

Comment: single instance of view model would be  `@model MyprojectName.Models.Layout` instead of `@model IEnumerable<MyprojectName.Models.Layout>` in view

Comment: @touinta `var model = new Layout() { Notifications  = notifications, Tasks = tasks }; return view(model)` and then in the view, `@foreach(var item in Model.Notifications){ ... }` etc.

Comment: If I do that then I can't get the fields that I need for each method.

Comment: Shouldn't your view Model class be LayoutViewModel not just Layout and it be kept within a ViewModel namesspace not Models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your queries in your action method both return collections of data. To accommodate this your view model needs to have two lists and needs to look something like this. You have to be able to store these collections in lists when sending them to the view:

```
public class Layout
{
     public IEnumerable<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

To populate these lists change the code in your action method to this. Create an instance of `Layout`, populate the two lists and then send the instance to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     Layout model = new Layout();

     model.Notifications = (from n in db.Notification
                            where n.NotificationIsSeen == true
                            select n);

     model.Tasks = (from t in db.Task
                    where t.TaskIsSeen == true
                    select t);

     return View(model);
}
```

Your view needs to accept and instance of `Layout`:

```
@model MyprojectName.Models.Layout

@foreach (var notification in Model.Notifications)
{
     <div>
          @notification.NotificationSubject
     </div>
}

@foreach (var task in Model.Tasks)
{
     <div>
          @task.TaskSubject
     </div>
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you it works! But the only problem I have is that when I go to another page It gives error about the models. How can I use this so to bee seen in all views

Comment: Explain to me what you are trying to do? I think maybe this might be another question. One question at a time :)

Comment: ok I mean that I need to display these data to every page not just at the index. In my layout page I call the Layout model. But when I click to another page I get the error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Myprojectname.Models.Notification]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Myprojectname.Models.Layout'."

Comment: I think maybe you need to make use of `TempData` or just reload the data when the new page loads. Your question is very broad as to what you want to achieve so it's quite difficult to answer.

Comment: Brendan Vogt I used RenderAction and partial views so no errors for now :)

Answer (score -1):

Please declare list type of model in you layout model

Layout Model

```
public class Layout 
{ 
 public IEnumerable<Notification> Notifications { get; set; } 

 public IEnumerable<Task> Tasks { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 Layout model = new Layout();

 model.Notifications = (from n in db.Notification
                        where n.NotificationIsSeen == true
                        select n);

 model.Tasks = (from t in db.Task
                where t.TaskIsSeen == true
                select t);

  return View(model);
 }
```

View

```
 @model MyprojectName.Models.Layout

 @foreach(var item in Model.Notifications)
 {
 // access your item.propertyname     
 }


@foreach(var item in Model.Task)
 {
 // access your item.propertyname
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using partial view for build the dynamic header

1 - create action with partial view and display data

2 - go to layout to call this

`@Html.partial("Action","Controller")`